# What happens when 3 phase AC motor running clockwise is suddenly reversed?

Tags: motor, ac, power-electronics, motor-controller

Considering motor as an iductive load, when current passes through the inductor it stores it as magnetic energy. By changing 2 phases in a running 3 phase motor would reverse the motor.

1. What happens to the stored magnetic energy in the motor inductance?
2. Will there be an "inductive kickback"?

Comment: The fuses/contrller blow, usually.  If you are lucky, the motor will not need a rewind and/or replacement bearings/shaft:(

Comment: see "plug reversing".

Answer (score 2):

There would be arcing at the contactor contacts, due to 'inductive kickback', every time an induction motor is switched off.

When a running motor is reversed, there would be a finite time between the motor switching off in the forward direction, suddenly stopping and then starting in the reverse direction. Hence the same arcing would result.

Such a reversal is called plugging and is one of the methods used to brake an induction motor (power is switched off before it reverses). The resulting high I²R dissipation in the rotor would overheat the motor and necessitate sufficient cooling time between braking cycles.

Comment: Yup, plugging is not super uncommon but certainly requires caution when designing.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the inductive energy which is realtivelly small, there is a kinetic energy of rotating mass. In case of induction motor reversal, the whole kinetic energy is dumped in the rotor, i.e it would glow or burn.

ad 1.) The energy is transformed into mechanical energy or heat.
ad 2.) There is no large kickback, since there is a free magnetic path in the machine.

Comment: Yes the kinetic energy is transmuted to heat energy,mostly in the rotor. But it would take a lot of serious abuse for that to cause it to glow or melt. Motors designed for North America per NEMA standards can accept a certain amount of plugging duty without serious consequences. IEC motors probably can too if selected for that purpose,. Maybe S8 or 9

Comment: @JRaef It depends on the load inertia. The whole kinetic energy (rotor + load) is dumped to rotor heat.